# Category colors in SSRS chart

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a bar chart in SSRS that has one category group and no series groups.  What I would like to know is if there is any way I can have each category show up as a different color, rather than all of them being a single color like SSRS wants to do?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this is to hard code the colors for each category in the Values' Properties -> Fill tab -> Color expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!DISPUTE_TYPE.Value = "Duplicate", "Red", 
 IIF(Fields!DISPUTE_TYPE.Value = "Eligibility", "Orange", 
 IIF(Fields!DISPUTE_TYPE.Value = "Corrected billing", "Green", 
 IIF(Fields!DISPUTE_TYPE.Value = "Additional information - Records", "Blue", "Yellow"))))
```

The downside is that you have to account for all values else they'll use the last "default" value (yellow in this code).

You could number each type in your query and use that number in a formula to create colors.